# Как сменить цвет в меню lua файла?

Tags: lua

Написал небольшой скрипт для игры самп 0.3.7, основной цвет красный,но я хочу узнать как делать смену цвета на нажатие
сам скрипт:

```
'abl = {}'
"local style = imgui.GetStyle()
local colors = style.Colors
local clr = imgui.Col
local ImVec4 = imgui.ImVec4"
"style.WindowRounding = 0
style.ChildWindowRounding = 1.5"
"colors[clr.TitleBg]                = ImVec4(255, 0, 0, 1)
colors[clr.TitleBgActive]          = ImVec4(255, 0, 0, 1)
colors[clr.TitleBgCollapsed]       = ImVec4(255, 0, 0, 0.1)"
```

Comment: А почему метка `python`? :)

Comment: потому что я тупой)

Answer (score 0):

- 255, 0, 0 - красный
- 255, 255, 0 - желтый
- 0, 255, 0 - зеленый

И так далее

Comment: не а как сделать чтоб при нажатии менялся цвет? я этого не понимаю

Comment: я не вижу как нажимать в вашем коде

Comment: игру ставить не хочется...)

Comment: дайте ваш дискорд,скину полный код

Comment: по правилам сообщества воспроизводимый пример должен быть в вопросе.

Comment: я просто первый раз на этом сайте,извиняюсь